# choices are not showing in the selectbox in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to add categories in my project. So that whenever user post a blog he will add category also but in the select box it is not showing I tried this :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post,Category,Comment

choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name','name')

choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)

class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','title_tag','author','category','body','snippet','header_image')
        widgets = {
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Title of the Blog'}),
            'title_tag' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Title tag of the Blog'}),
            'author' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'','id':'elder','type':'hidden'}),
            'category' : forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':"blog's category"}),
            'body' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Body of the Blog'}),
            'snippet' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Template code

```
 <h2>Add Post...</h2><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.media}}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input value="Post" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi please confirm Category has data in it.

Comment: can you show the template code

Comment: yes category has data but it only shows 3-4 data. and not adding extra data or category

Comment: then show the template code